# C++ an iterator "for loop" idiom which moves in step sizes > 1 and allows for non-random-access reverse iterators

Tags: c++

Sorry for the question wording. Please edit if you can think of a better way to phrase the question.

To loop over a `std::vector v` one step at a time, we have a lot of options. Here are some that immediately come to mind:

```
1. for ( auto & elem : v )
2. for ( int i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; ++i )
3. for ( auto begin = v.begin() ; begin < v.end() ; begin++ )
```

Now I want to restrict the discussion to the iterator based approaches, since I will eventually be interested in other containers. For instance, let's say I have a method that juts accepts the `begin` and `end` iterators:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foo( Iterator begin, Iterator end ){
    for ( ; begin < end ; begin++ ){
       ...
    }
}
```

The issue with this is that this will not work with more general containers since we can't simply increment the iterator for all containers. Ok let's fix that:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foo( Iterator begin, Iterator end ){
    for ( ; begin < end ; std::advance( begin, 1 ) ){
       ...
    }
}
```

Aha, but there is another issue, notably, what happens if somebody gave us a reverse iterator... Ok. If we are worried about that, we could simply change this to

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foo( Iterator begin, Iterator end ){
    for ( ; begin != end ; std::advance( begin, 1 ) ){
       ...
    }
}
```

Here is my question... How do I now accommodate a step size larger than 1 while acknowledging that I could have a reverse, non-random access iterator?

Specifically, what is the most lightweight `test` I could insert in the following code:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foo( Iterator begin, Iterator end, const size_t step ){
    for ( ; test(begin, end) ; std::advance( begin, step ) ){
       ...
    }
}
```

EDIT:

It was pointed out that the advance function may be undefined if I step past the end of the container. That bug needs to get fixed as well.

Comment: Oh is it? I wasn't aware of that. Let me check the docs.

Comment: I thought that that wasn't the case because the docs for `rbegin` show the != idiom: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rbegin/

Comment: 1) Note from docs of `std::advance`: "_The behavior is undefined if the specified sequence of increments or decrements would require that a non-incrementable iterator (such as the past-the-end iterator) is incremented_". So, if a call to `std::advance` would require incrementing past the end iterator - the behavior is undefined. 2) The comparison of `begin < end` only works with random access iterators (such as the one returned by `std::vector`), but not all iterators used in STL are random access iterators.

Comment: Is there any reason you think `for ( ; begin != end ; std::advance( begin,  step ) ){` is bad? I'm not sure to understand the question... except if you specifically ask "how can I make sure not to go beyond the end iterator?".

Comment: @YSC It's undefined if the end is less than `step` increments away.

Comment: @interjay THis is what I'm saying. If this is the question, I know how to answer, if it is not, I don't understand it.

Comment: @YSC Yes, it seems to be the question. The reverse iterator is a red herring here - what OP meant is an iterator which isn't random access.

Comment: I am worried about reverse iterators AND non-random access iterators

Comment: Would be a little bit tedious, but you could leave the increment out of the for loop declaration and instead do some work at the end, having another loop there which does step many iterations, each time increments by one and then checks if it is at the end, if so, the outer loop is terminated somehow.

Comment: I was not aware of the undefined behavior when using the advance function. In this case, I will post an edit. And you guys can comment on the update

Comment: Non RA iterators don't provide `operator<`; (`test` in the question). But the problem of potentially incrementing the end operator remains even with RAI (`std::vector<int> v({7}); std::advance(v.begin(), 2);` remains UB...).

Comment: @bremen_matt You don't need to care for the reverse iterators - they behave *exactly* the same as normal iterators of same class (RA, bidirectional, ...). Just that the order of elements is reverse.

Comment: Ok. Then the biggest pain point is how to deal with step sizes greater than 1... Should I ask a post a new question with regards to that problem?

Comment: Note that with range-v3, it would be something like `for ( auto & elem : v | ranges::view::reverse | ranges::view::stride(step) ) {/*..*/}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a template that performs the iteration with given step size and checks for the termination condition after every increment. It also calls a function with the dereferenced iterator.

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Fct>
void foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end, std::size_t step, const Fct& f) {
   if (begin == end)
      return;

   while (true) {
      f(*begin);

      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < step; ++i)
         if (++begin == end)
            return;
   }
}
```

This should work for any non-random-access iterator, e.g.

```
const auto print = [](const auto& arg){ std::cout << arg << "\n";  };

std::list<int> l{42, 43, 44, 45, 46};

foo(l.crbegin(), l.crend(), 3, print);
```

or e.g. with input iterators.

```
foo(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<char>(), 2, print);
```

Comment: What an explicit dispraise :) I'm happy to see a more elegant solution. Probably a dispatch on the iterator category would be the way to go.

Comment: I doubt that there will be a much cleaner solution because one needs to define what should happen when you accidentally advance past the end of the container. Probably for that reason there is not a cleaner C++ solution.

Comment: For instance, your function simply returns when you overstep. Perhaps we should still pass `begin` to the function `f` even though there wasn't a full step size.

Comment: Is such a behavior intuitive? A plain old for loop with an integral counter and a step size greater than 1 doesn't do anything for a last iteration step that has not been a full step size...

Comment: I know what you mean. But my use case is calling `swap_ranges` between two containers from multiple threads. To do this, we break the container into chunks, process it, and then merge the results. I need to work with that last chunk even if it is smaller than the others.

Comment: @bremen_matt I think that would be a good and useful question to ask! Chunking and processing data in an elegant way is a common problem and if you make the question about solving that, you might get some "prettier" answers.

Answer (score 2):

Trivial answer:
replace

```
std::advance( begin, step )
```

by

```
for (int i=0;i<step;i++) {if (begin!=end) std::advance(begin,1);}
```

.
INSIDE the for loop increment.
Because the onliest way to check **if you are past** an element in an unordered manifold is if you check at each step. That is what gives modulo encryption its cryptographical strength.
In the case you got an order but just do not know whether it is working forward or reversed, you could check at the beginning whether

```
bool bigger_at_beginning=begin > end;
```

and make the comparison dependent on that bool, like

```
bigger_at_beginning ? (begin<end) : (begin>end)
```

but that is not as straight-forward, and will not work on completely unordered iterators, so I prefer the former way of doing.

Answer (score 2):

The really big problem with hopping more than one single element is *not* the test you are seeking – it is avoiding incrementing the iterator past the end of the container (which is undefined behaviour)!

Following scenario:

```
std::vector<int> v({7});
for(auto i = v.begin(); i < v.end(); i += 2);
```

Yes, I even skipped `std::advance` deliberately for comparison...

You increment the iterator beyond the vector's end! While that might *seem* to run nicely, it is still undefined behaviour.

If you want to have a generic solution based on iterators, you need to know how many elements are yet left:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end, typename Iterator::difference_type step)
{
    if(begin != end)
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            // use *begin
            if(end - begin <= step)
                break;
            begin += step;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this only works for random access iterators, of course. But if we replace the use of operators with `if(std::distance(begin, end) <= step)` and `std::advance(begin, step)` in the RA variant above, we get a solution that works for *all* types of iterators.

You might want to stay with for simplicity/maintainability.

Solely: With non-RA iterators, you need to do `step` single one-position hops *twice*, once for calculating the distance, once for actually advancing. So you might prefer doing both manually in one single go for these. In a general solution, you'd check for the type first:

```
for(;;)
{
    // use *begin;

    if constexpr
    (
        std::is_same_v<typename Iterator::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>
    )
    {
        if(std::distance(begin, end) <= step)
            goto LOOP_EXIT; // alternatively (here only): break;
                            // (wanted to be consistent with else branch...)
        std::advance(begin, step);
    }
    else
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < step; ++i)
        {
            if(std::advance(begin, 1) == end)
                goto LOOP_EXIT;
        }
    }
}
LOOP_EXIT:
// if no further instructions follow:
(void) 0;
```

If you need that more often, you might move this into your own

```
template <typename Iterator>
Iterator advance_not_beyond(Iterator begin, Iterator end, size_t step)
{ /* ... */ }
```

as long as we don't get a `std::advance_not_beyond` by the standard...